# Authenticating an AD user using Membership Provider

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-membership, membership-provider

I am running into a weird problem.

**Synopsis**

My login page can authenticate against SQL uses or AD users. To identify if a user is an AD user, user name should contain a backslash.

The logic for SQL works fine, but I am getting the most generic error (`Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`) when authenticating a user against AD.

**Details**

For *SQL users*, I've `CustomSqlMembershipProvider()`. The call is like this:

```
if(Membership.Provider.ValidateUser(userName, userPassword))
    userAuthenticated = true;
```

The class `CustomSqlMembershipProvider()` sends the credentials to SQL database.

For *AD users*, I've this logic:

```
if (Membership.Providers["ADMembership"].ValidateUser(userName, userPassword))
    userAuthenticated = true;
```

This above `if` statement is generating the error `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

**Web.config**

```
<add name="ConnectionStringAD" connectionString="LDAP://it.CompanyName.local" />
...
<membership defaultProvider="CustomSqlMembershipProvider" userIsOnlineTimeWindow="30">
  <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add name="CustomSqlMembershipProvider"
        type="Authentication.MembershipProviders.CustomSqlMembershipProvider"
        connectionStringName="SqlProviderConnectionString"
        enablePasswordRetrieval="false"
        enablePasswordReset="true"
        requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false"
        requiresUniqueEmail="false"
        maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5"
        minRequiredPasswordLength="6"
        minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0"
        passwordAttemptWindow="10"
        applicationName="/" />

    <add name="ADMembership"
         type="System.Web.Security.ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"
         connectionStringName="ConnectionStringAD"
         connectionUsername="it\LDAPuser"
         connectionPassword="LDAPuserPassword"
         connectionProtection="Secure"
         maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5"
         attributeMapUsername="sAMAccountName" />

  </providers>
</membership>
```

I strongly think that there is some small issue, but I could not figure it out.

---

**Software**

- Visual Studio 2010
- .NET 4.0
- Server 2008 R2 with SP2 (10.50.4000)
- IIS 7.5

Answer (score 0):

Its not an answer directly but few suggestion to narrow down the problem:

1. Try changing defaultProvider in web.config. Set it to ADMembership.
2. Break down the call:

---

```
if (Membership.Providers["ADMembership"].ValidateUser(userName, userPassword))
    userAuthenticated = true;
```

---

to

---

```
var activeDirectoryProvider = Membership.Providers["ADMembership"];

if(activeDirectoryProvider  != null)
{
    userAuthenticated = true;
}
else
{
    Log("activeDirectoryProvider is null");
}
```

3. This is wild guess :). Rename "ADMembership" to "ADMembershipProvider" suffixing "Provider" just in case some convention stuff.